# How to detect if UI is got touched

Tags: c#, android, user-interface

I'm beginner and I was creating a Main Menu on my mobile game using unity2d that have plain background and three text(Create Room, Join Room, Options) in the middle and I want something to happen when I click one of these.

I don't need the actual code to join or create room, I just need to know how can I execute a code when the text got click(touch, tap).

I need to know the command for clicking the UI Text on Mobile.

Or it is not possible to detect if UI Text got click(touch, tap)?